# Value of tag property disappears

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm busy with a simple application. It reads xml and puts the information in a treeview.

I do this by creating TreeNodes and nest them, and finaly, return the root treenode. Because I want to show some extra information when a treenode is selected, I put the information in the tag property of the TreeNode. In this way, I should be able to retrieve the information when the node is selected.

But when I try to retrieve the information in the Tag property, it says the value = null.

Here is the code where I fill the tag. This is in a function which is recursively used to read the XML dom. treeNode is a paramater given to this function.

```
if (treeNode.Tag == null)
{
treeNode.Tag = new List<AttributePair>();
}
(treeNode.Tag as List<AttributePair>).Add(new AttributePair(currentNode.Name, currentNode.Value));
```

This is the event where a treenode is selected

```
private void tvXML_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (tvXML.SelectedNode.Tag != null)
    {
    }
    if (e.Node.Tag != null)
    {
    }
}
```

Both values evaluate to null. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This works for me - may sound stupid, but are you sure you're not changing the nodes somewhere to set the Tag to null?

Comment: You have to use the debugger and step into the code to see what actually happens

Comment: In between, i do not touch the tag property anymore. And yes, i've used the debugger. In the first method, i see the tag getting it's value, and in the seccond, i see the value is empty.

Comment: Do you by chance have the Localizable property set on the form?

Comment: Due to lack of time, failed to give more details. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you posted should work as-is. Something else in your code, code that you didn't post here, is causing this to break. It could be clearing the Tag, it could be a data binding set on the tag, etc.

Without seeing all your code, the best I can do is guess and help you isolate the problem.

Here's what I'd do: [setup Visual Studio to allow stepping into the .NET framework source code with the debugger](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx). Then, set a breakpoint on the setter for the TreeNode.Tag property. After you set the tag in your code to your AttributePair List, see when it gets set again. The breakpoint will hit, you'll look at the stack trace and see what exactly is clearing your Tag property.

Answer (score 3):

If using Tag property isn't in principle, I'm recommend inherit TreeItem:

```
public class MyTreeNode : TreeNode
{
    public List<AttributePair> list; 

    public MyTreeNode (string text,List<AttributePair> list) : base(text) 
    {
       this.list = list;
    }
    //or
    public MyTreeNode (string text) : base(text) 
    {
       this.list = new List<AttributePair>();
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
private void tvXML_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (tvXML.SelectedNode is MyTreeNode)
    {
       MyTreeNode selectedNode = tvXML.SelectedNode as MyTreeNode; 
       selectedNode.list.Add(.., ..);
    }
    if (e.Node is MyTreeNode)
    {
       MyTreeNode node = e.Node as MyTreeNode; 
       node.list.Add(.., ..);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are assigning the values after Select event. Otherwise you can maintain a dictionary of TreeNode and tag values as workaround.

Comment: the class that assigns the value, builds the treenodes, so it is not possible that it assigns it after the select event. I thought of that workaround too, but i would like to avoid it

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring/initialising your List object somewhere above (outside of the inner scope you are in) and when you assign to the .tag property - don't create a new list but rather assign previously created List object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private TreeViewItem _subsender;
    private object _senderTag;
    public TreeViewItem _sender
    {
        get {
            return _subsender;
        }
        set
        {
            _senderTag = value.Tag;
            _subsender = value;
        }
    }
```

Got the same problem this the solution that i found

Just don't use the .tag but _senderTag

(don't change the lines in the set for some reason :D )

(You cant just reset the tag (maybe new TreeViewItem ))